# Flink Data Stream Conversion and Expose to REST end point

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have spring boot application and integrating with Apache Flink. I wanted to read data from Kafka system, and expose them to REST end point.

The below is my simple data,

```
    @GetMapping("/details/{personName}")
    public String getPersonDetails() throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env =  LocalStreamEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "group_id");


        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("test-topic-1",
                new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
        consumer.setStartFromEarliest();
        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(consumer);

        stream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public String map(String value) throws Exception {
                logger.info(value);
                return value;
            }
        }).print();
        env.execute();

        return "hello world";

    }
```

My problems is,

- My Kafka returns String value as below,

```
"id":"1","PersonName":"John","address":"Bristol","weight":"34", "country":"UK","timeStamp":"2020-08-08T10:25:42"}
{"id":"2","PersonName":"Mann","address":"Bristol","weight":"88", "country":"UK","timeStamp":"2020-08-08T10:25:42"}
{"id":"3","PersonName":"Chris","address":"Leeds","weight":"12", "country":"UK","timeStamp":"2020-08-08T10:25:42"}
{"id":"4","PersonName":"John","address":"Bristol","weight":"44", "country":"UK","timeStamp":"2020-08-08T10:25:42"}
{"id":"5","PersonName":"John","address":"NewPort","weight":"26", "country":"UK","timeStamp":"2020-08-08T10:25:42"}
{"id":"6","PersonName":"Mann","address":"Bristol","weight":"89", "country":"UK","timeStamp":"2020-08-08T10:25:42"}
```

How can i return by converting into JSON by applying filters. For example if my input from REST call is "John" i want to group them and sum the weight values and return as JSON (only Name, and Weight).

- Second problem,
  I can't stop execute environment. Is there any alternatives? I checked Flink document, i didn't get any for my situation.
- Third problem,
  I wanted to keep in environment is eager loading, tried to using static block but it takes more time also.

NFRS:

I have massive data in Kafka, so wanted to scale and fast processing.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might need to spend more time reviewing the Flink documentation. But in a nutshell...

1. Add a `MapFunction` that parses the string into JSON, extracts the name and weight, and outputs that as a Tuple2<String, Integer> or some custom Java class.
2. Do a groupBy(name field), followed by a `ProcessFunction` that sums the weight and saves it in state.
3. Use `QueryableState` to expose the state (the summed weights) to code that's running as part of your program's main() method.
4. In your main method, implement a REST handler that uses the `QueryableStateClient` to get the weight for a given name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am spending more time on reading document also.  One more clarification, Is there any way to fetch data and stop ```StreamExecutionEnvironment env =  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();``` instance? In my usecase, the REST API get data from Kafka and return result set.  ```env.execute();``` method keeps running.

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch data and stop"? How do you know when you've processed enough data from Kafka? Flink streaming jobs typically assume unbounded (never ending) sources of data.

Comment: kkrugler after reading the material, yeah i got it. Now going with another approach. However thanks for your reply.